# GSON different value for same key

Tags: java, android, gson

I am currently using Gson and Retrofit for my Android project which automatically parse the API needed for me. However, I realized that the API contains a value in which it can be a boolean or an Object for different types of data in the API.

For example

```
    ...
        {
          "media": false,
        },
        {
          "media": {
            "mp4": "http://sample.com/something.mp4",
"jpg": "http://sample.com/something.jpg",
         }
        },
    ...
```

How exactly should my Gson model be like?

```
@SerializedName("media")
Object images;
```

Comment: Use generic type T.

Comment: Can you change the key of json? It makes confusing meaning.

Comment: Could have it as `JsonElement`.

Comment: "Wrong JSON format acceptance"  never such JSON accept same key with different values bad way of development. AVOID TYPE CASTING IN App.

Comment: I wish I can alter the API. But I'm creating a third-party app which uses the API. :(

Gonna try using generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong using the `Object` to parse. While using the parsed data just use `instanceof` to check which type the data is.

For ex: `object instanceof Boolean` for boolean.

**EDIT:**
Create a model class for urls. Like :

```
public class Urls {

@SerializedName("mp4")
private String mp4Url;

@SerializedName("jpg")
private String jpgUrl;

public String getMp4Url() {
    return mp4Url;
}

public String getJpgUrl() {
    return jpgUrl;
}

}
```

Now check

```
if(parsedObject instanceof Urls) {
    Urls urls = (Urls) parsedObject;
    urls.getMp4Url;
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I "convert" the object to another Gson class where I can `m.getMp4()` or `m.getJpg()`? I tried force converting and Gson.fromJson yet nothing seems to work.